# Difference Netbeans - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, email, netbeans

I tried to implement the post from Kirit Vaghelathat that I found under "Send e-mail using java" in my Netbeans project but it gives a failure all the time:

> "DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 465, isSSL false
>   DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   Oops something has gone pearshaped, tried to send an e-mail !"

I tried exactly the same in Eclipse, and there it works.

Only difference I can see is in Eclipse I run it as a stand alone class:

```
public class hellotest extends Object{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
//code
```

While in Netbeans it is part of a bigger project and it will be called from another class:

```
public class SendEmail extends Object{
    public void sendEmail(){
//code
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong in Netbeans?

**Added on 22 Jan 2015 :**

I did some smaller changes to where Netbeans has to find its libraries (as suggested in the Oracle javaMail API FAQ) but with no result. Debug messages are changed a bit as follows :

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 465, isSSL false
Oops something has gone pearshaped, tried to send an e-mail !
```

In Eclipse it is still working, I compared the code word per word, it is identical.

Comment: It seems like your class path is different, are you using same JDK?

Comment: as far as i know : yes ... please tell me how to check

Comment: Netbeans is using  "1.7.0_40; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.0-b56". Can't find similar message in Eclipse...

Comment: Try to (preferably in both IDEs) print System properties (whereever in your programs) - `java.class.path`, `java.home`, `java.vendor`, `java.version` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: Netbeans java.class.path = R:\_Bxxx\Java software\xxx\lib\JavaMail\javax.mail.jar;R:\_Bxxx\Java software\xxx\build\classes
Netbeans java.home = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre
Netbeans java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
Netbeans java.version = 1.7.0_40

Eclipse java.class.path = null
Eclipse java.home = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
Eclipse java.vendor = null
Eclipse java.version = 1.7.0_51

Comment: So, try to use same jdk in Eclipse (probably easier) or jre in NetBeans to run it again...

Comment: I managed to switch in Eclipse, resulting in +/- the same debug messages as shown above so i think i have to change to \java\jre7 in Netbeans. Unfortunately i can't find where to change it ... and honestly i don't really understand this ...

Comment: That was just a test ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, for replying in comments.

It is security problem.

Compare content of JRE/JDK security folders. In my system the paths are:

JRE

"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\security"

JDK

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\lib\security"

Versions are not really important.

And remember what is in your JRE is what is correct = working for you...

Comment: I could find 3 security folders : 1=C:\PF\Java\jdk 1.7.0_67\jre\lib\security ; 2=C:\PF(x86)\Java\jdk 1.7.0_40\jre\lib\security ; 3=C:\PF(x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security.    Files in 1 are different than those in 2 or 3. Files in 2 and 3 are the same. Difference is in files "blacklisted.certs" and "javafx.policy" : .certs is in 1, .policy is in 2 and 3.

Comment: You wrote it is working with 1.7.0_40 (2), so use this one and compare it with the one from JRE (3). Later you can check with updated JDK (1), but for now stick to the one, which is working.

edit: I saw the edit, thinking...

Comment: By files are the same you meant names or sizes (in bytes if possible) also ?

Comment: dates differ, sizes in kb only for cacerts : 81 or 82 kb

Comment: Backup the not working one and copy here the one from JDK. You can print the content using `..\..\bin\keytool.exe -list -keystore cacerts` if you are in security folder...

Comment: 1) I copied all files from (3) to (2) and tried but without succes  2)-keystore asks for a password ...

Comment: Last comment was too early, i forgot to restart, so IT WORKS ! problem solved.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that, passwords is empty (simply hit enter), it seems there is more trusted authority in the JRE and server you are connecting to is using certificate signed by exactly this missing authority...